# How can I get a users department via REST query in SharePoint Online and on premise ADFS?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I need to create a list with entries of users and their departments. To do that, I want to create a little script to populate that list. What I need is to query our on premise ADFS for the users department.

Until now I can read the department of the current user with this request:

```
http://XXX.sharepoint.com/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties?$select=Department
```

I also can request a list of all users with this one:

```
https://XXX.sharepoint.com/_api/web/siteusers/
```

Now, according to documentation I could request the department of any user with this query address:

```
https://XXX.sharepoint.com","/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetUserProfilePropertyFor(accountName=@v, propertyName='Department')?@v='USERNAME'"
```

That query fails with this error (german version):

```
error: {"error":{"code":"-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException","message":{"lang":"de-DE","value":"Fehlender oder ung\u00fcltiger Abfragetext \"accountName\"."}}}
```

If I query the users, I get a property called LoginName with this formatting, that I used as USERNAME:

```
i:0#.f|membership|username@companydomain.de
```

So to my question:

In what way do I need to format the USERNAME variable so that the query succeeds? Is it possible to query other users than the current one, if our ADFS is on premise?